# Cant install PyTables at windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, installation, hdf5, pytables

I try to install the PyTables module. I use Windows 7 (x32), Python 2.7.3 (x32), Cython 0.16, Visual Studio 2008 (9.0). At cmd.exe 'run as administrator' write: 'python setup.py install --hdf5="C:\Program Files\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9"'.

But there are unresolved external symbols and build failed:

```
* Found numpy 1.6.2 package installed.
* Found numexpr 2.0.1 package installed.
* Found Cython 0.16 package installed.
* Found HDF5 headers at ``C:\Program Files\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include``, libra
ry at ``C:\Program Files\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\lib``.
* Could not find LZO 2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
* Could not find LZO 1 headers and library; disabling support for it.
* Could not find bzip2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
cythoning tables\linkExtension.pyx to tables\linkExtension.c
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'tables.utilsExtension' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -IC:\Python27\lib\
site-packages\numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-win32.egg\numpy\core\include -I"C:\Program Files
\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tctables\
utilsExtension.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.obj -Isrc
 -DH5_USE_16_API
Found executable C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe
utilsExtension.c
c:\program files\hdf group\hdf5\1.8.9\include\H5public.h(47) : fatal error C1083
: Не удается открыть файл include: stdint.h: No such file or directory
error: Command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /n
ologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-win32.egg\numpy\core\include -I"
C:\Program Files\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python
27\PC /Tctables\utilsExtension.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExt
ension.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API" failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. have been trying to install tables for 5 days now. Any light on this?

Comment: @G-XP-MIA: URL from Accepted answer helps me! http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables

Comment: Yes, sorry for expressing myself badly. I have already tried that, but I'm having a hard time installing whl. Can't seem to get it going.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing Python packages with C extensions from source on Windows is difficult.  Luckily, there are people who build these kits and make them available: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables

Install it from a binary kit, you'll be much happier.

Comment: thanks a lot, there are not binary installers on official site, so I thought... thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this worked for me once I found the correct wheel.

Comment: how to install the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [pytables installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21607974/11236901)

Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68740234/11236901

Or just install a stable version for your os from: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables)

And install the file in your directory with:

- pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl