# pytables installation failed

Tags: installation, pip, hdf5

I do:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade tables
```

I get:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
.. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
   You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
   library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
   variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
```

however:

```
$ echo $HDF5_DIR 
/opt/hdf5/
$ ls /opt/hdf5/
bin  include  lib  share
$ ls /opt/hdf5/lib/
libhdf5.a     libhdf5_hl.la  libhdf5_hl.so.8      libhdf5.la        libhdf5.so libhdf5.so.8.0.1
libhdf5_hl.a  libhdf5_hl.so  libhdf5_hl.so.8.0.1  libhdf5.settings  libhdf5.so.8
```

What's wrong? How to debug? I already tried to set HDF5_DIR to /opt/ or to /opt/hdf5/lib.

Answer (score 14):

I also had the same error on Debian sid trying to work in a local virtualenv. To work around it I did:

```
apt-get build-dep python-tables
HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ && pip install tables
```

... now it's working.

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep python-tables` was sufficient for me! (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: All I had to do was `sudo apt-get install hdf5-serial-dev`, then `pip install tables`.

Comment: A lot has changed since 2014, good to know the -dev package works for pytables out of the box now :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev` for me, on a debian-based docker image in 2019

Comment: Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 16.04 required install of libhdf5-dev followed by: HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/   pip install tables

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this easily in OSX with virtual environments using the following code:

```
    $ brew install hdf5
    $ pyvenv test
    $ workon myvenv # to get pytables working within the virtual environment myvenv
    $ pip install numpy numexpr cython
    $ pip install tables
```

(taken from andreabedini post in https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/385)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem, but I'm using the leading edge not the pip release (see Aside).
I also tried pointing to the library itself

```
export HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/libhdf5.so.6
```

but it did not work.

Aside: You can try the leading edge of PyTables if you think your bug may have been addressed recently:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables
```

.

The build (that was caused by pip install...) seemed to progress further after I installed the dev version of the hdf5 library (libhdf5-openmpi-dev). The build still failed for other reasons, but it's another direction you could try.

Comment: `HDF5_DIR` requires a directory not a file, `export HDF5_DIR=/local/johndoe/hdf5`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can install the stable wheel file for your os for pytables from here:
[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables)

Use this command to check for which file to download
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip debug --verbose

And this command to install the wheel file
pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl

Answer (score 0):

I tried **everything** without success. The only way I could I achieved was using nehalecky's answer I got here:

> https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/219

In a nutshell, you should do these 2 commands, correcting the path, of course:

```
sudo python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace --hdf5=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/
sudo python3 setup.py install --hdf5=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/
```

Hope it helps!