# How to install local HDF5?

Tags: python

I tried to install deepdish package but got following error messages.  Any idea how to install HDF5? I use Window 10. Thanks.

```
Collecting deepdish
  Using cached deepdish-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\shih\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from deepdish) (1.19.4)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\shih\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from deepdish) (1.19.4)
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.6.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shih\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shih\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-80q8kjoy\\tables_963fe20f85be42d1b00213dd1b7f026c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shih\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-80q8kjoy\\tables_963fe20f85be42d1b00213dd1b7f026c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\shih\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fjhii8cp'
         cwd: C:\Users\shih\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-80q8kjoy\tables_963fe20f85be42d1b00213dd1b7f026c\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    H5close2aqtkhue.c
    C:\Users\shih\AppData\Local\Temp\H5close2aqtkhue.c(2): warning C4013: 'H5close' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'hdf5.lib'
    * Using Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
       You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
       library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
       variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try it: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607974/pytables-installation-failed>

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I installed Anaconda Python and the issue went away.